# Django-haystack is unable to index location fields

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to index a bunch of addresses with django-haystack. My searchindex is:

```
class AddressIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    street = indexes.CharField(model_attr='street')
    city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city')
    location = indexes.LocationField(null=True)

    def prepare_location(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.location.point
        except AttributeError:
            return None

    def get_model(self):
        return Address
```

The searchindex has more fields of course, but this suffices. When I try to index this by running `./manage.py update_index -k4 -b100 -v2 location` (the index is stored inside the location app) everything goes great as long as `prepare_location` returns None. As soon as it returns something (eg. the point 0.000, 0.000) I get an error from Solr mentioning something about incompatible dimensions.

The exact error is `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: incompatible dimension (2) and values (POINT (0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000)).  Only 0 values specified`. I thought "maybe it doesn't like this point" and added 0.0000000000000001 to both the `point.x` and `point.y`, but the error stayed the same (except now it mentioned the new coordinates).

Anybody got an idea what's going on here?

I'm using:

- Python 2.7.5+ (yes, it actually says that when I run python --version)
- Django 1.5.2
- django-haystack 2.1.0
- Solr 4.3.0
- pysolr 3.1.0

On Ubuntu 13.10 with all the latest updates installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `django-haystack` doesn't do a particular, important bit itself. It doesn't convert a GeoDjango Point into the required "lat,lon" format, but just passes through the Point object on to the XML document.

So instead of doing this:

```
def prepare_location(self, obj):
    try:
        return obj.location.point
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

One need to be doing this:

```
def prepare_location(self, obj):
    try:
        return "{lat},{lon}".format(lat=obj.location.point.y, obj.location.point.x)
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

It would have been a hell of a lot easier if I'd just [read the documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/spatial.html)...